# Pick rows in pandas DataFrame that have one of the values in an iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to pick only the rows which have a specific column with any value belonging to a list.

I have tried to implement it directly through `where()` but I get the typical error when trying to get a boolean from an array comparison:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My code:

```
desired_values = (2,4,6,8)
target_column = 'Target Column'
df = pandas.read_csv(r'example.csv')

filtered_df = df.where(df[target_column] in desired_values).dropna()
```

While this code works:

```
filtered_df = df.where(df[target_column] == 2).dropna()
```

And this also works:

```
#This outputs True as the first value is '4'
print(df[target_column][0] in desired_values)
```

So I figure that panda's `where()` picks each row and tests whatever condition you throw at it, which leads me to think that my approach should work, given that, for each row, you can apply the comparison as I wrote it, and that testing with `==` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify this, your where condition doesn't work on its own:

```
df[target_column] in desired_values
```

creates the same ValueError. I suggest the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

```
desired_values = (2,4,6,8)
target_column = 'Target Column'
df = pandas.read_csv(r'example.csv')

# Define a function to apply to each row
def filterit(row):
    return row[target_column] in desired_values

# Get a true/false index from our filter function
idx = df.apply(filterit, axis=1)
filtered_df = df[idx]
```

That should help explain this one, which is a bit more concise:

```
filtered_df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x[target_column] in desired_values, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited this answer a zillion times. My first answer didn't use only the provided target_column. If you look back at my edits, the first solution checks the entire CSV/DF row against the desired_values instead of just target_column.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it for me! Thanks for giving, not only a concise solution, but also a more extended and understandable solution!